# AVLTree compare two trees (operator== implementation)

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, comparison, avl-tree

Im overriding the operator== to compare two trees. The problem I have is I need them to be equal if they have the same elements inside and not if the elements are placed in identical places.

If in first the tree I add 6 and 8 and in a second tree I add 8 and 6, the operator should return true. Thanks in advance

I have an iterator but Im unsure if itll execute in a faster time and how to use it properly.

```
int identicalTrees(node* a, node* b) {
    if (a == NULL && b == NULL)
        return 1;
 
    if (a != NULL && b != NULL) {
        return (
            a->data == b->data &&
            identicalTrees(a->left, b->left) &&
            identicalTrees(a->right, b->right)
        );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use the iterator that you have. It's impossible to suggest how to use it since you didn't include it.

Comment: Can you iterate through your AVL tree? If so then two tress are equal if they have the same elements in the same order. If you can't iterate through your AVL tree then now is the time to write some methods to do that. Then you can apply those methods to this problem.

Comment: The interface of the iterator is what's interesting, not its internals and its equality operator.

Comment: @molbdnilo woops, I added them.

Comment: This looks a lot like a "normal" iterator interface as seen in the standard library, so you could start reading about those in your favourite C++ book. (It's going to be very similar to comparing two `std::vector`s or `std::list`s with the use of iterators.)